Aligning a 3D face mesh to face the camera
I'm working on aligning a 3D face mesh using PyVista for visualization. My goal is to position the nose tip at the origin (0, 0, 0) and ensure that the eyes are aligned along the Y-axis so that the face is directly facing the camera. Here's what I'm aiming to achieve:
I have already extracted the nose tip, left eye, and right eye coordinates and attempted to translate the mesh so that the nose tip is at the origin. However, aligning the face properly with the eyes on the Y-axis has been challenging. Here is what I achieved so far:
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np
import yaml
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

# Path to the OBJ file
obj_file = "checkpoints/custom/results/examples/epoch_20_000000/000002.obj"

# Load the points from the YAML file
with open('selected_point_ids.yaml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.safe_load(file)
    point_ids = data['point_ids']

# Read the OBJ file
mesh = pv.read(obj_file)

# Retrieve the coordinates of the selected points from the mesh
selected_points = mesh.points[point_ids]

# Assume the points are [nose_tip, left_eye, right_eye]
nose_tip = selected_points[0]
left_eye = selected_points[1]
right_eye = selected_points[2]

# Translation: Move the nose tip to the origin (0, 0, 0)
translation_vector = -nose_tip
translated_mesh = mesh.copy()
translated_mesh.points = mesh.points + translation_vector

I need help for rotating the mesh. Or at least some directions to look after.

I don't think you have sufficient information. You can fix the camera to point to the nose tip, and you can roll the camera to keep the eyes horizontal, but then you still have a degree of freedom moving the camera in the xz plane, modifying how high or low you're looking at the face. All of these camera positions will respect your requirements to keep the focal point and the projection of the eyes aligned. How can you tell when you're looking at the face from straight ahead?

You already placed the origin at the correct place. Now you just need to rotate, such that the eyes align with the y-axis. Attaching this to your already working code should solve your issue:
eye_vector = right_eye - left_eye  # Calculate the vector between eyes
eye_vector_normalized = eye_vector / np.linalg.norm(eye_vector)  # to avoid scaling and simplify angle calculation
y_axis = np.array([0, 1, 0])
rotation_axis = np.cross(eye_vector_normalized, y_axis)  
angle = np.arccos(np.dot(eye_vector_normalized, y_axis))
rotation = R.from_rotvec(rotation_axis * angle)

# Apply the rotation to the mesh
rotated_mesh = translated_mesh.copy()
rotated_points = rotation.apply(rotated_mesh.points)
rotated_mesh.points = rotated_points

As Andras Deak -- Слава Україні mentioned in the comment, your problem is not unambiguous, as you have one open degree of freedom. Once you satisfied your two requirements (nose at the center and eyes aligned with y-axis), you can still rotate around the y-axis, keeping both conditions fulfilled. To fix the open DoF, you could add an additional constraint (e.g., mouth distance to the x- or z-axis).
